# Returning multiple rows as one row

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is a simple query and it's results using SQL Server:

```
SELECT Notes
FROM DailyTaskHours
WHERE Notes IS NOT NULL
    AND Notes <> ''
    AND NonScrumStoryId = 2264
```

[image]

I would like one row with one column returned. How do I accomplish this?

Comment: which database please?

Comment: Step 1 - specify your database engine.

Comment: SQL Server, I have updated the tags.

Comment: Step 2 - read Jason's answer

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: post your desired result. This could be one row with multiple columns, or one row with one column.

Comment: Sorry, one row with one column.

Comment: @DavidTunnell Then this has been asked many many many times before. Just do a quick search with the terms "group_concat" and "sql-server"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm figuring you need them all as a single cell, rather than PIVOT them out.

Try this

```
With 
MyTable as
(
        Select 1 Id, 'Contacted the P6 Admin Reps to find out what to do.' Notes
Union   Select 2, 'Sent and email to request status.'
Union   Select 3, 'updated ticket and confirmed issue was resolved.'
) 
Select 
    (
        SELECT SUB.Notes + ' ' 
        FROM MyTable SUB
        FOR XML PATH('')
    ) TextValue
```

Here is the answer I get:

```
TextValue
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Contacted the P6 Admin Reps to find out what to do. Sent and email to request status. updated ticket and confirmed issue was resolved. 

(1 row(s) affected)
```

Answer (score 1):

If this is a SQL Server Database I believe you can implement the `PIVOT` operator in a way like this:

```
select [1] as field1,
  [2] as field2,
  [3] as field3
from
(
  select col1, row_number() Over(order by col1) rn
  from yourtable
) src
pivot
(
  max(col1)
  for rn in ([1], [2], [3])
) piv
```

Comment: Could you possible update this in the context of the above query. It would help me understand what you mean.